# Google Ads API PHP examples' differences

Tags: php, google-api, google-ads-api

I've installed Google API with composer and get authenticated. There are no problems about that but when i started to look at to examples from the web site and downloaded files they are really different.

In [developer web site](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/php/optimization#get-keyword-ideas) example codes starts with like:

```
// Include the initialization file
require_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/init.php';

require_once UTIL_PATH . '/MapUtils.php';
```

But in [downloaded files](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/v201609/Optimization/EstimateKeywordTraffic.php) they start with like:

```
namespace Google\AdsApi\Examples\AdWords\v201609\Optimization;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsServices;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSession;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSessionBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201609\cm\Keyword;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201609\cm\KeywordMatchType;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201609\cm\Language;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201609\cm\Location;
...
```

There are no "init.php" in latest version (201609) anymore so i think on web site the examples are outdated. Examples that come with downloaded files working good but when i try to learn something different there are no online examples from developers site.

I think I am missing something but don't know what is that is. Can anyone explain me why those two examples are different? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation has just been updated. Please have a look at that [page](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/php/optimization#get-keyword-ideas) again.
Sorry for this confusion.

In the future, I highly recommend to post you questions either in our github repo's [issues](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/issues) (if it's related to PHP client library only) or our [AdWords API forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/adwords-api) instead, as we're monitoring these two sites regularly and you could get answers much faster. :)

Best,
Thanet

Comment: Thanks, after I posted my comment on the other thread its updated and now my issues are all resolved. But Google must have more examples on those codes. The documentation is really confusing.